# Using 2 CROSS APPLY in XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm using below XML to fetch the `ClauseCode` but it's not returning any data for the below query.

```
<Policy>
 <Plans>
    <Plan>
       <ProductEndorsementClauses>
        <ClauseCode>3</ClauseCode>
      </ProductEndorsementClauses>
  </Plan>
  <Plan>
       <ProductEndorsementClauses>
        <ClauseCode>1</ClauseCode>
    <ClauseCode>2</ClauseCode>
      </ProductEndorsementClauses>
  </Plan>
  <Plan>
       <ProductEndorsementClauses>
        <ClauseCode>5</ClauseCode>
    <ClauseCode>4</ClauseCode>
      </ProductEndorsementClauses>
  </Plan>
 </Plans>
 </Policy>
```

Here is my query :

```
  select proposaid,
            ,Col1.value('(/*/ProductEndorsementClauses/ClauseCode)[1]','nvarchar(max)') 
            from Policy p 
            CROSS APPLY data.nodes('/*/Plans/Plan') AS Tbl(Col)
            CROSS APPLY Tbl.Col.nodes('/ProductEndorsementClauses/ClauseCode') AS TblPec(Col1)
            where Col1.value('(ProductEndorsementClauses/ClauseCode)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') in ('1','3')
```

Comment: I *assume* the reason isn't because you effectively have `proposaid,,Col1.value` (double comma)?

Comment: Seems like `nodes('/ProductEndorsementClauses/ClauseCode')` should be `nodes('ProductEndorsementClauses/ClauseCode')` (among the other typographical errors you have).

Comment: I also recommend adding `text()` at the end when using `value` like that; it's quicker due to the way that SQL Server handle the XML. I.e. `MY.MC.value('(MyNode/text())[1]','int')`.

Answer (score 0):

For inspiration:

```
declare @x xml = N'
<Policy>
 <Plans>
    <Plan>
       <ProductEndorsementClauses>
        <ClauseCode>3</ClauseCode>
      </ProductEndorsementClauses>
  </Plan>
  <Plan>
       <ProductEndorsementClauses>
        <ClauseCode>1</ClauseCode>
    <ClauseCode>2</ClauseCode>
      </ProductEndorsementClauses>
  </Plan>
  <Plan>
       <ProductEndorsementClauses>
        <ClauseCode>5</ClauseCode>
    <ClauseCode>4</ClauseCode>
      </ProductEndorsementClauses>
  </Plan>
 </Plans>
 </Policy>'

 select @x

 --all clause code values
 select t.col.value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(10)')
 from @x.nodes('Policy/Plans/Plan/ProductEndorsementClauses/ClauseCode') as t(col);

 --only clause code values that have at least a 1, 3 clause code in their parent ProductEndorsementClauses
 select t.col.value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(10)')
 from @x.nodes('Policy/Plans/Plan/ProductEndorsementClauses[(./ClauseCode/text() = "1") or (./ClauseCode/text() = "3")]/ClauseCode') as t(col);


 --result only when exists at least a  1 or 3
 select t.col.value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
 from @x.nodes('Policy/Plans/Plan/ProductEndorsementClauses/ClauseCode') as t(col)
 where @x.exist('Policy/Plans/Plan/ProductEndorsementClauses/ClauseCode[text() = "1" or text() = "3"]') = 1;



 declare @Policy table 
 (
    proposaid int,
    data xml
 );

 insert into @Policy(proposaid, data)
 values(1, N'
<Policy>
 <Plans>
    <Plan>
       <ProductEndorsementClauses>
        <ClauseCode>3</ClauseCode>
      </ProductEndorsementClauses>
  </Plan>
  <Plan>
       <ProductEndorsementClauses>
        <ClauseCode>1</ClauseCode>
    <ClauseCode>2</ClauseCode>
      </ProductEndorsementClauses>
  </Plan>
  <Plan>
       <ProductEndorsementClauses>
        <ClauseCode>5</ClauseCode>
    <ClauseCode>4</ClauseCode>
      </ProductEndorsementClauses>
  </Plan>
 </Plans>
 </Policy>'),
 (2, N'
<Policy>
 <Plans>
    <Plan>
       <ProductEndorsementClauses>
        <ClauseCode>13</ClauseCode>
      </ProductEndorsementClauses>
  </Plan>
  <Plan>
       <ProductEndorsementClauses>
        <ClauseCode>11</ClauseCode>
    <ClauseCode>12</ClauseCode>
      </ProductEndorsementClauses>
  </Plan>
  <Plan>
       <ProductEndorsementClauses>
        <ClauseCode>15</ClauseCode>
    <ClauseCode>14</ClauseCode>
      </ProductEndorsementClauses>
  </Plan>
 </Plans>
 </Policy>');


 select *
 from @Policy;

select p.proposaid,
    t.col.value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
from @Policy as p
cross apply p.data.nodes('Policy/Plans/Plan/ProductEndorsementClauses/ClauseCode') as t(col)
where p.data.exist('Policy/Plans/Plan/ProductEndorsementClauses/ClauseCode[text() = "1" or text() = "3"]') = 1;
```